# when clicking ajax.Action to redirect to new page instead updating

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've got an action method `ImportShow` which returns me a partial view `ImportShow` in which I've got some ajax.ActionLinks which when clicked update the div 'importpartupdate' (they just updates the div with new ajax.actionLinks with other routevalues returned from the Action).

My problem is - when there is no more records for the propertied of teh vuewModel GroupMenu returned from this partial view I want to redirect the user to new controller 'Product' and it's index action. 
SO I have made the check and it's really redirecting me to PropductController. The problem is that I have set `UpdateTargetId = "importPartUpdate"` and the result is that my whole nee product page is inserted only in the `importPartUpdatediv`. How can I solve this 
3

Here is my Controller

```
public virtual ActionResult ImportShow(String id, String menuID, string articlegroupID, int? counter)
        {



                GroupMenu p_GroupMenu = new GroupMenu();
                p_GroupMenu.LanguageName = p_country;



                p_GroupMenu.MenuHistory = p_GetMenuHistory.ToList();
                p_GroupMenu.MenuLeft = p_GetMenuLeft.ToList();

                if (p_GetMenuLeft.Count == 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Product", new { id = id, menuID = menuID, articlegroupID = articlegroupID, counter = 0 });

                }
                else
                {
                    return PartialView("ImportShow", p_GroupMenu);
                }


            }

        }
```

Here is my partial view

```
model  MvcBeaWeb.GroupMenu
```

```
<div class="importPartUpdate">
    <ul>
        @{
            if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (MvcBeaDAL.WebServiceBeaMenu item in Model.MenuLeft)
                {

                  <li id="@item.ID">

                        @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.SpecialWord, "ImportShow", new { id = Model.LanguageName,menuID=@item.ID,counter=1},new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "importPartUpdate", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })

                  </li> 
                }
            } 
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can u show the Index action of the Product controller?

Comment: no as I said there is no problem with the  index action of the  product Controller. As I said the problem is with setting  updatetargetID = which means updating only this div and as a result  loading the whole page in this div